Is checking for trivial solution in floating point functions safe?
I am writing code to implement a pocket calculator and one of the requirements for my application is that the user be isolated from floating point quirks such as sin(M_PI) not returning 0.
Since I am writing this for an ARM cortex M0, memory is limited which means nothing fancy like binary coded decimals, I have to stick to doubles. I use newlib as a math library, which has all the functions that I need.
To protect the user from floating point implementation issues such as the one pointed out above, a solution I came up with is to modify sin() and check for trivial cases, such as the input being a multiple of M_PI.
For example:
double better_sin(double z) {
    double pi_ratio = z / M_PI;
    if (floor(pi_ratio) == pi_ratio) return 0;
    else return sin(z);
}

does the job.
My question is, are there any pitfalls to this? Speed is unimportant since a human and a keyboard are involved so the response time needed is in the ms range.
I tried a simple benchmark to see if this could screw up things around M_PI but it seems to have at least the same "precision" as the normal sin().
int main(void) {

    double a;
    double result;
    
    printf("For input M_PI\n");
    a = M_PI;
    printf("\n");
    result = sin(nextafter(a, 3));
    printf("libc's sin(M_PI-): %.10e \n", result);
    result = better_sin(nextafter(a, 3));
    printf("better_sin(M_PI-): %.10e \n", result);
    printf("\n");
    result = sin(a);
    printf("libc's sin(M_PI): %.10e \n", result);
    result = better_sin(a);
    printf("better_sin(M_PI): %.10e \n", result);
    printf("\n");
    result = sin(nextafter(a, 4));
    printf("libc's sin(M_PI+): %.10e \n", result);
    result = better_sin(nextafter(a, 4));
    printf("better_sin(M_PI+): %.10e \n", result);

    printf("\n\n");

    a = 50e6 * M_PI;
    printf("\n");
    result = sin(nextafter(a, 3));
    printf("libc's sin(50E6 * M_PI-): %.10e \n", result);
    result = better_sin(nextafter(a, 3));
    printf("better_sin(50E6 * M_PI-): %.10e \n", result);
    printf("\n");
    result = sin(a);
    printf("libc's sin(50E6 * M_PI): %.10e \n", result);
    result = better_sin(a);
    printf("better_sin(50E6 * M_PI): %.10e \n", result);
    printf("\n");
    result = sin(nextafter(a, 4));
    printf("libc's sin(50E6 * M_PI+): %.10e \n", result);
    result = better_sin(nextafter(a, 4));
}

which returns:
libc's sin(M_PI-): 5.6655388976e-16 
better_sin(M_PI-): 5.6655388976e-16 

libc's sin(M_PI): 1.2246467991e-16 
better_sin(M_PI): 0.0000000000e+00 

libc's sin(M_PI+): -3.2162452994e-16 
better_sin(M_PI+): -3.2162452994e-16 


libc's sin(M_PI-): -4.9343786466e-08 
better_sin(M_PI-): -4.9343786466e-08 

libc's sin(M_PI): -1.9541464078e-08 
better_sin(M_PI): -1.9541464078e-08 

libc's sin(M_PI+): -4.9343786466e-08 
better_sin(M_PI+): -4.9343786466e-08 

It's going to be a lot of code writing to make sure that all functions of a scientific calculator return the right answer for trivial cases (like above), so if I am missing something bigger, any input is appreciated.

This question is similar to: How dangerous is it to compare floating point values?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should always check floating points within a tolerance, eg if (abs(floor(pi_ratio) - pi_ratio)) < 1e-8), or maybe use FLT_EPSILON.

@KenY-N: Floating-point values should rarely be compared with a tolerance. One of the few use cases for that is in a test program that is checking whether a subject program has produced an unacceptable value. Other than that, comparing floating-point values should be avoided, not kludged. Comparing with a tolerance trades one kind of error (false rejections) for another (false acceptances), so it risks creating more bugs. It should not be recommended.

If you truly want your calculator to behave exactly like a pocket calculator, and if the pocket calculator you want it to behave like is decimal, and you want to avoid all "quirks", no matter what calculations the user performs, I suspect you're really going to have to implement true decimal arithmetic.  Look up Cordic methods.  You may not have much memory, but I bet the pocket calculator you're trying to emulate had less.

This effort is largely futile. No numerical system can fully implement real-number arithmetic, not even arbitrary precision arithmetic or symbolic arithmetic.
Checking for multiples of M_PI will fail because π is irrational (and transcendental). M_PI does not capture the full value of π, so multiples of it get further and further from multiples of π, and other floating-point values will be closer to a multiple of π than the nearest multiple of M_PI is. Checking whether a number is a multiple of M_PI will not tell you whether its sine is near zero.
Additionally, you would have to kludge lots of other artifacts of numerical arithmetic, such as 1/49*49-1 not producing zero.
You need to rethink the requirement “that the user be isolated from floating point quirks…” and either drop it or state fully and precisely what it is, in a way that fully considers what might be achievable with the properties of numerical arithmetic.

Your point about multiples of M_PI is well taken, but if a more narrowly-construed goal of avoiding surprises when users try to compute sin(M_PI) (which is certainly a common enough case, judging by questions about it here on SO), it seems to me that the obvious test if(z == M_PI) return 0; would work, and might even be appropriate.

I understand that with a finite precision there always will be a number that breaks sin() and whichever implementation we use to define it, it's a periodic function after all. Can I make it behave "better" before it inevitably breaks? can I implement it with degrees such that sin(180 * k) = 0 until the integer k is larger than some number?

@Leo chux's answer describes possible implementations using degrees. __sinpi is probably your best bet, if newlib supports it.  Your hypothetical sind(180 * k) should work correctly even for very large values of k.

@SteveSummit unfortunately newlib doesn’t have that function. I might try to implement it or copy it from somewhere else. The problem with newlib is that sin() is used in cpow() as well, so integer powers of negative numbers, i.e. cpow(-3, 3) return a small imaginary part because sin(3 * M_PI) doesn’t return 0.

@Leo make sure you chase chux's link to his sind implementation.  That should be almost as good as __sinpi.

M_PI is not π.
M_PI is a floating point (rational value) value near π (irrational).
So "floating point quirks such as sin(M_PI) not returning 0" is not a quirk, but should provide a correct result such as 1.2246467991e-16.


To protect the user from floating point implementation issues

With trigonometric functions, offer the user the opportunity to (maybe optionally) use degrees which offers some results with no error.
With degrees sind(180.0*some_integer) returns an exact value of zero.
See also -0.0 issues
When implementing double sind(double degrees), do range reduction first, scale to radians and then call a standard trig function. Example.

With C2X, there is sinpi(x) (sine of π×x) which allows a simpler sind().  Some library extensions presently offer similar functions.
double sind(double degrees) {
  return sinpi(degrees/180.0);
}


floor() v. trunc()
if (floor(pi_ratio) == pi_ratio) return 0; is not a symetric test when pi_ratio < 0.
Perhaps if (trunc(pi_ratio) == pi_ratio) return 0;
Note that for all |pi_ratio| > 253, this will result in 0.0

it’s also true that sin(M_PI / 2) should not return 1 but a number very close to it, so why is it different than sin(M_PI)? After all forcing sin(M_PI) to be zero would cause an error similar to machine epsilon. Would that cause problems down the line? I am thinking about a chain of calculation that involves sin(M_PI) returning 0. Would that cause harm?

@Leo "it’s also true that sin(M_PI / 2) should not return 1 but a number very close to it," --> No.  The C function sin(M_PI / 2) result is far closer to 1.0 than the next double  which is  DBL_EPSILON * (1 or one-half away from 1.0).  Thus even though the math sine(M_PI / 2) is not 1.0, 1.0 is the closet representable double.

@Leo  "After all forcing sin(M_PI) to be zero would cause an error similar to machine epsilon. " --> Yes in a linear magnitude sense of DBL_EPSILON, but not in a relative sense.  In the case of math sine(M_PI / 2), the result is about 1.22e-16 and there are about 0.4*2^64 different double between that and 0.0.  Recall FP are not distributed linearly but logarithmically overall and then linearly within a power of 2.  Perhaps graph where the blue dots' x-values are in double steps and the y-values billions+ of different double.

those ~2^64 different double are not reachable through sin(x) when x is ~ M_PI, though. As the graph you linked to shows, the result of sin('M_PI' +- epsilon) can only be 1.2246467991e-16 +- epsilon (roughly speaking).

@Leo To be clear, are you using epsilon as the C library  DBL_EPSILON?  If not, then what?  'M_PI ± DBL_EPSILONis stillM_PI. Try printf("%.17g %.17g\n", M_PI, M_PI + DBL_EPSILON).  "can only be 1.2246467991e-16 +- epsilon" --> 1.2246467991e-16 ± DBL_EPSILON covers a very large number of possibledouble`.

Sorry, I misspoke. In my original code I use nextafter() on M_PI to test sin() around that value. From that point of view, the smallest variation to the input x can only generate a change to the output sin(x) in the order of a few 1e-16. That’s what I meant with 2^64 values of double being unreachable.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
